# How do i know when a double click is made on focused element with voice over accessibility?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, voiceover

Facing an issue where double tapping with voice over on, the link inside focused UITextView is not opening in Safari in iOS 9. It works fine in iOS 10 and 11. Any suggestions for same?

Also i need to know when the user double taps on screen to perform action on focused item with voice over on , also which view was in focus?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your second question about [handling focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167471/ios-accessibility-button-focussed/27209702#27209702) and [activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288410/voiceover-how-to-implement-button-that-behaves-like-keys-in-calculator) have been previously answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please add more details and example code for your first question.

Comment: Hey @Justin , So the problem is , in iOS 10 , upon double tapping the link in UITextView (with link data detector on) , the link is activated and TextView's shouldInteractWithURL is called with the url. However in iOS 9 , upon double tapping the selected link in focus , shouldInteractWithURL is not called , it is however called when the second tap of double tap is held a bit long, Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST QUESTION**: to open a link in a `UITextView`, there's a [specific VoiceOver gesture](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/voiceover.html#OpenLink) I already explained in a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55144836/3825084) and that should always work.

**SECOND QUESTION**: if you want to know the focused element on which a double tap is made, the best way is to use the  [`UIAccessibilityFocus`](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#focus-an-element) informal protocol using the `accessibilityElementIsFocused` method for instance.

Take a look at the provided links where code snippets are available *(Objc + Swift)*.